# Angular-cli: ng build -prod fails due to error in ./~/angular-cli/~/css-loader?sourcemap&minimize!./~/postcss-loader!./~/quill/dist/quill.snow.css

Tags: angular, build, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-style-loader

I am having very weird issue here today while doing **ng build -prod**. The log given by the failure:

```
ERROR in ./~/angular-cli/~/css-loader?sourcemap&minimize!./~/postcss-loader!./~/quill/dist/quill.snow.css

ERROR in ./~/angular-cli/~/css-loader?sourcemap&minimize!./~/postcss-loader!./~/quill/dist/quill.core.css

ERROR in ./~/angular-cli/~/css-loader?sourcemap&minimize!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourcemap!./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/angular-cli/~/css-loader?sourcemap&minimize!./~/postcss-loader!./~/@ec-digit-uxatec/eui-styles/dist/assets/fonts/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css
```

I am getting above error while building with Maven as well. Below are my dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
"@angular/core": "2.3.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
"@angular/http": "2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
"@angular/router": "3.3.1",
"@types/quill": "^0.0.29",
"angular2-busy": "^1.0.2",
"angular2-modal": "^2.0.2",
"chart.js": "2.4.0",
"class-transformer": "0.1.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"moment": "2.16.0",
"ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.10",
"ng2-modal": "0.0.22",
"ng2-select": "1.1.2",
"ng2-translate": "4.0.1",
"ng2-validation": "3.1.2",
"primeng": "2.0.6",
"quill": "^1.2.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.7.2"
```

},

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
"codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
"jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "4.0.9",
"style-loader": "^0.18.2",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "3.15.1",
"typescript": "2.0.10"
```

}

I have no clue about this. I appreciate for your help in advance.

Comment: It's due to your css importing issue. Try to import the css in this format @import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";

Comment: But how come my other project building correctly with same settings as generated by Angular-cli. I didn't changed anything manually.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: remove sourceMap=true and include htmlLoader under plugins like this new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
           options: {
               htmlLoader: {
                   minimize: false // workaround for ng2
                }
           } 
        }),